# For a non-geocentric ellipsoid, how does the Lat/Long/Ell Ht & semi-major axis & flattening implicitly define the centre of the ellipsoid?

Tags: geodesy

For example if we compare the AGD84 (Australian Geodetic Datum) with GDA94 (Geocentric Datum Australia), the centre of the AGD Datum is 200 metres different to GDA, because it is a best fit to the geoid.

But how is this difference realised (implicitly) given only the Lat/Long/ Ellipsoidal Height of a Point (Johnstone), the semi-major axis (a) and the flattening (f)? I realise that (a) is different by 23 metres, but it is the angle between the 2 datums that makes the most difference, this is what I am trying to get a handle on.

Asking another way, how could I calc the ECEF coords for the centre of the AGD, to see how different it is to GDA?

Asking yet another way, how to determine the shift & angles between the axes of of AGD & GDA?

I already have the GDA manual - http://www.icsm.gov.au/gda/gdatm/gdav2.3.pdf
 and am working through writing C++ code for this. I also understand how AGD is not very consistent, so a conversion between the 2 datums requires the use of a model, it is just that I am trying to truly understand the mathematical difference between the two.

Sorry for the particularly nerdy question, & thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is defined by the *datum shift* between the two reference ellipsoids. The shift itself is defined with a transformation (7 param. Helmert, 4 param,....) using 3D cartesian coordinates (X, Y, Z) which are calculated from ellipsoid coordinates (lat, lng, elevation).

The transformation (parameters) is usually derived from a set of points which have coordinates known in both systems, using least squares adjustment.

Heres a link how to calculate 3D cartesian coordinates from lat-lng-elevation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum#Conversion_calculations

Comment: Cheers @U2ros, that makes sense. I can see how the transformation process would work, given some common points. It was just that the official definition of AGD never seemed to mention a shift, nor any angular tilts, or any common points for that matter. I found the value of the shifts on-line, after some extensive searching. I guess it is all a bit academic, because AGD is not consistent, so requires a model to transform. But I have an idea of the theory now (thanks to your help). My link above has some formulae for doing conversions to XYZ, but thanks again for your time & effort. 8+)